# Datatables only shows 15 when I have 60

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I use Datatables 1.9.4 and Jquery : 1.12

I use datatables to show data when viewing the php page :

```html
 <table id="table_data" class="datatable table table-hover table-striped table-condensed" data-url='<?php echo site_url('****/***'); ?>'></table>
```

I created a filter to modify the data through an ajax call :

```js
$(document).on("click", "#needtobevalide", function() {
    $("#table_data").DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "order": [],
            "ajax": {
                url:"<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/***/*****",
                type:"POST"
            },
            "bDestroy": true
    });
});
```

But and when I click on the button `needtobevalide` the datatable  fills up with 15 rows but if I console.log my result I have 60 rows

The datatable show : "Showing 1 to 10 of 15 entries"

I also have tried to use `"iDisplayLength":` 60, with no success

Comment: have you disabled pagination?

Comment: I just tried, always the same

Comment: can you create a working jsfiddle/snippet?

Comment: Hum, I can't the data are sensitive, but I will try

Comment: I think my data is badly formatted.

And that creates confusion in the table

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following code after initialising dataTables

```
$("#table_data").DataTable({
    "paging": false
    // then add other attributes here
});
```

You can read more at: https://datatables.net/reference/option/paging

Alternate way:

include "bPaginate": false, as parameters. As seen here: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/filter_only.html

Comment: Doing the same thing

Answer (score 0):

I finally succeeded, I simply changed the version of DataTables ...